# Many2many field in a tree view, how to show it in two or more columns in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

`Many2many` field in a tree view, how to show it in two or more columns.
For example in Orders view i want to show `journal_id` and `statement_id` of journal from `statement_ids` in point of sale.

```
<record id="pos_order_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">order.tree</field><field name="model">pos.order</field><field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_order_tree"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
    <field name="statement_ids" widget="many2many_tag">
        <tree > 
            <field name="journal_id"/>
            <field name="statement_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field> 
</xpath>
</field>
</record>
```

I have added `widget="many2many_tag"` so that may be it is not displaying the other two columns.

Comment: Can you share your efforts code in your question ?

Comment: <record id="pos_order_tree" model="ir.ui.view"><field name="name">order.tree</field><field name="model">pos.order</field><field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_order_tree"/><field name="arch" type="xml"><xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after"><field name="statement_ids" widget="many2many_tag"><tree >
<field name="journal_id"/><field name="statement_id"/></tree></field </xpath></field></record>
statement_ids = fields.One2many('account.bank.statement.line', 'pos_statement_id', string='Payments', states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, readonly=True)

Comment: Edit your code in your question. It's hard to understand in comment section.

Comment: @majid Why you don't add this two column in sale.order as related fields

Comment: This would be new thing for me to implement , related field ok i do

Comment: Anonymous miliana !i have tried related fields to adding on model but view doesn't showing any value

Answer (score 0):

We can show more then two columns for *many2many* or *one2many* field using following example:

```
<field name="many2many_ids">
    <tree> 
        <field name="field_1"/>
        <field name="field_2"/>
        <!--  <field name="field_n">  -->
    </tree>
    <!-- <form>
         Design your form view
         </form> -->
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your **many2many** field:

```
style="column-count:2;"
```